# Change the background of the ShareActionProvider's view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I want to change the background of the `ShareActionProvider`'s view that gets put into the `ActionBar` as a `MenuItem`. I can't seem to find the right attribute in styles to do this. I need to change the background of the entire thing, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like that:

```
ActionBar actionBar= getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc));
```